# Merge over 50% of matched two df lists of list strings in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have two df:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name1': ['ID1', 'ID2','ID3','ID4','ID5','ID6','ID7'], 'col1': ["S3,S22,S44", "S133,S32,S334", "S13,S24,S45", "S1,S2,S4,S5", "S3,S4,S5", "S3,S2,S5", "S38,S42,S9"],'col2': ['ab', 'ac','ad','ae','af','an','ak'],})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name2': ['Ik3', 'Ik1','Ik2','Ik7','Ik5','Ik6','Ik5'], 'col1': ["S3, S44, S22,S54", "S133, S32,S334, S30", "S13, S24,S45", "S11, S21,S4, S5", "S3, S4,S5", "S3, S22,S5", "S3, S4,S9, S10, S13"],'col2': ['ab', 'ae','ac','ad','af','ab','ak']})
```

df1

```
name1 col1          col2
ID1   S3,S22,S44    ab
ID2   S133,S32,S334 ac
ID3   S13,S24,S45   ad
ID4   S1,S2,S4,S5   ae
ID5   S3,S4,S5      af
ID6   S3,S2,S5      an
ID7   S38,S42,S9    ak
```

df2

```
name2   col1              col2
Ik3     S3,S44,S22,S54    ab
Ik1     S133,S32,S334,S30 ae
Ik2     S13,S24,S45       ac
Ik7     S11,S21,S4,S5     ad
Ik5     S3,S4,S5          af
Ik6     S3,S22,S5         ab
Ik5     S3,S4,S9,S10,S13  ak
```

Would like to compare two df of col2 lists and merge who have more than 50% matching and leave the rest empty:

Desired output:

```
name1   col1          col2 M_name2  M_col1            M_col2 percentage 
ID1     S3,S22,S44    ab   Ik3      S3,S44,S22,S54    ab     75
ID1     S3,S22,S44    ab   Ik6      S3, S22,S5        ab     75
ID2     S133,S32,S334 ac   Ik1      S133,S32,S334,S30 ae     50
ID3     S13,S24,S45   ad   Ik2      S13,S24,S45       ac     100
ID4     S1,S2,S4,S5   ae   Ik5      S3,S4,S5          af     50
ID5     S3,S4,S5      af   Ik5      S3,S4,S5          af     100
ID6     S3,S2,S5      an   Ik5      S3,S4,S5          af     75 
ID7     S38,S42,S9    ak   NaN      NaN               NaN    NaN
```

I have tried with isin funtion :

```
df1[df1.col2.isin(df2.col2)]
```

but not getting desired output. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: In second row, why `S133, S32,S334`  does not match `S133, S32,S334, S30` by 50%?

Comment: Your expected output seems wrong.. or at doesn't match your description

Comment: In order to make this useful, I'd encourage you to edit your question to address the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your description and output don't match. However, here is some code to hopefully get you started.

```
def get_ratios(df1, df2):
  for a,b in zip(df1.col2, df2.col2):
    clean = lambda s: list(map(str.strip, s.split(',')))
    vals1, vals2 = clean(a), clean(b)

    inter = set(vals1).intersection(vals2)
    ratio = len(inter)/max(len(vals1), len(vals2))

    yield ratio
```

```
s = pd.Series(get_ratios(df1, df2))
```

Then `merge`

```
(df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'col1': 'nma1'}), 
          on=['col3'])
    .assign(percentage=s)) #.where(s > 0.5)
```

---

```
  col1          col2_x col3 nma1               col2_y  percentage
0  ID1     S3, S22,S44   ab  Ik3     S3, S44, S22,S54    0.750000
1  ID2  S133, S32,S334   ac  Ik1  S133, S32,S334, S30    0.750000
2  ID3   S13, S2 4,S45   ad  Ik2         S13, S24,S45    0.666667
3  ID4    S1, S2,S4 S5   ae  Ik7      S11, S21,S4, S5    0.000000
4  ID5       S3, S4,S5   af  Ik5            S3, S4,S5    1.000000
5  ID6       S3, S2,S5   as  Ik6            S3, S2,S5    1.000000
6  ID7       S3, S4,S9   ak  Ik5  S3, S4,S9, S10, S13    0.600000
```

Comment: Good effort at inferring what OP meant.  I'm still confused but what you've provided looks like a good start.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer below. I created a function to get the percentage match and put NaN for colum nma1 if percentage is below 50%. Thanks.

```
def get_percentage(x, y):
    '''
       Convert columns from string to list
       Compute the percentage
       Return NaN if less than 50% match
    '''
    x=[i.strip() for i in x.split(',')]
    y=[i.strip() for i in y.split(',')]
    percent = int(round((100.0 * len(set(x) & set(y))) / len(set(y)),0))
    return np.NaN if percent < 50 else percent  

# Use merge using both index
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('', '_y')).rename(columns={"col1": "name1", "col1_y": "nma1"})
# Get the percentage using apply/lambda functions
df['percent'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_percentage(x.col2, x.col2_y), axis=1)
# Remove not needed columns
df.drop(columns=['col2_y', 'col3_y'], inplace=True)
# Check if percent column is NaN
df['nma1']=df.apply(lambda x: np.NaN if np.isnan(x.percent) else x.nma1, axis=1)
df
```

Result:

```
  name1 col2         col3   nma1    percent
0   ID1 S3, S22,S44     ab  Ik3     75.0
1   ID2 S133, S32,S334  ac  Ik1     75.0
2   ID3 S13, S2 4,S45   ad  Ik2     67.0
3   ID4 S1, S2,S4 S5    ae  NaN     NaN
4   ID5 S3, S4,S5       af  Ik5     100.0
5   ID6 S3, S2,S5       as  Ik6     100.0
6   ID7 S3, S4,S9       ak  Ik5     60.0
```

Comment: This works fine but only takes the percentage of each row from two different df,  (eg: col1 row comapres to col1 of another df but not with col1 to col3/4/5/6 of another df) but i want it to be compared with all-againsit all between two df and only keep them with highest percentage?

Comment: @rajiv; I'll change my response.. pls also update your question to specify what you want. thanks.